# C Input homework

Tags: c, input, scanf

I am very new to C and am working on a homework problem. We need to write a program that takes in 10 numbers from the user and than outputs the average, highest, and lowest number. I have what looks like correct code but the output is just way off. Here is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10;

    printf("Enter 10 grades sperated by commas, then press enter: ");
    scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,&num9,&num10);getchar();

    int numbers[] = {num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10};

    int avg = (num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10)/10;

    printf("The average is: %d",avg);

    int high  = num1;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > high) {
            high = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The highest grade is: %d",high);

    int low = num1;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] < low) {
            low = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The lowest number is: %d",low);

    return 0;
}
```

If someone could give me some insight into what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: why dont you accept 10 numbers into the integer array itself.

Answer (score 3):

At your call to `scanf`, you aren't taking the **address** of each `numX`. You only take the address of `num9` and `num10` when you pass them all to `scanf`.

What you want is:

```
scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&num1,&num2,&num3,&num4,&num5,&num6,&num7,&num8,&num9,&num10);
```

In C, the `&` operator gives you the address of the variable (also known as a pointer).  The `scanf` function expects you to pass it *pointers* to variables, so it can modify the actual variable.

Also, to make your code a bit less unwieldy, you might want to consider getting rid of all those `numX` variables and just reading directly into the input array.

Comment: +1 also don't use `,` in formatting string otherwise input `,` separated numbers

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fscanf.html) and answer:

1. What type of value does scanf expect to correspond with the "%d" format specifier?
2. `int x;` What is the type of x? What about &x?
3. If I'm prompted for 10 values, and I only enter 9 values, followed by "Ooops!", what will scanf return?
4. Following on from that scenario, what would you expect getchar() to return? Which type of character would getchar() need to return in order for `scanf("%d", &num10);` to successfully read a value?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would focus on separation of concerns. Make a function that reads input, another function that returns the minimum, another function that returns the maximum, followed by a function that returns the average. Also, I would probably look into using an array to collect all of the data you are trying to store as opposed to declaring a huge pool of variables, save yourself from all of that typing. So let's prototype this array function:

**Prototype:**

```
int* get_numbers(int* size); // should return a pointer to that array
```

**Implementation:**

```
int* get_numbers(int* size)
{
    int* numbers = NULL;

    // collect data...

    return numbers;
}
```